# Python installation does not have sqlite3 library

Tags: python, sqlite, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

Trying to install Google Cloud Platform and got this warning mesasge

```
This python installation does not have sqlite3 library. Please upgrade your set of dependencies to include sqlite3 as otherwise gcloud commands will stop working in near future.
```

I checked if I have sqlite3 installed by typing sqlite3 in terminal and I got this

```
Last login: Sun Jul 30 17:13:58 on ttys000
J-2:~ j$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.12.2 2016-04-18 17:30:31
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .quit
```

I can't figure out what is missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve the issue? Were you able to solve it alternatively?

Answer (score 1):

This means that your setup tools aren't updated and might possibly be obselete.

You can try fixing this issue by:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

If this doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev libpcap-dev libpq-dev
```

I hope it will work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing it with pip...

Try this:

```
pip install pysqlite
```

and if that doesn't work just this:

```
pip install sqlite
```

what version of python are you using because it became pre-installed in python `version 2.5`

Comment: I'm on python 2.7.12.

pip install sqlite does not work. 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x9/5z2bwmss7z19whl0v8pdrxpc0000gn/T/pip-build-xdtm99/sqlite/

Comment: pip install pysqlite does not work. 
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/x9/5z2bwmss7z19whl0v8pdrxpc0000gn/T/pip-build-zWlMn9/pysqlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x9/5z2bwmss7z19whl0v8pdrxpc0000gn/T/pip-LCenyy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x9/5z2bwmss7z19whl0v8pdrxpc0000gn/T/pip-build-zWlMn9/pysqlite/

Comment: If you go into the python interpreter and type `import sqlite3`, what is the response?